# How to initializeShell in XBAP/Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, xbap

In WPF/PRISM when you create the shell it will be assigned to`App.Current.MainWindow`. However in a WPF in Browser (XBAP) the line:

```
App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
```

fails with the error message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'XBAPClient.Page1' to type 'System.Windows.Window'.

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{            
    return this.Container.GetExportedValue<Page1>();
}

protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    base.InitializeShell();
    App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
    App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

How can I load the shell?

Comment: If you using XBAP you using Page instead of Window. So you can't cast Shell to Window. For more information check this thread: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/31058?ProjectName=compositewpf

Comment: update: I have followed the first comment. The instructions were good. However still no luck. Investigating why its not running. But at least its building. Thanks

Comment: @kmatyaszek Unfortunately `CreateShell` is called first, before `Page1.xaml.cs` can set `Bootstrapper.ShellPage = this`; Hence it returns a always null shell.  Do you have any advice?

Comment: I have found the solution, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XBAP `Application.Current.MainWindow` is `MS.Internal.AppModel.RootBrowserWindow`.

You should only assign your page to window content like this:

```
...
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    base.InitializeShell();    
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = Shell;
}
...
```

Comment: You are the star! Now it actually works. How did you figure that out? +1

Comment: I just debugged code and tried to fix that issue :)